# How to commission in twig?

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

I have function to payments

```
public function calculateClientCost(Transaction $transaction)
{
    if ($transaction->getPaymentType() == Order::PAYMENT_TYPE_ALTERNATIVE) {
        return $this->container->getParameter('commission_alternative_price');
    }

    if ($transaction->getPaymentType() == Order::PAYMENT_TYPE_PRICE) {
        return $transaction->getPrice();
    }
}



public function calculateCommission(Transaction $transaction)
{
    if ($transaction->getPaymentType() == Order::PAYMENT_TYPE_ALTERNATIVE) {
        return $this->container->getParameter('commission_alternative_price');
    }

    if ($transaction->getPaymentType() == Order::PAYMENT_TYPE_PRICE) {
        return round($this->container->getParameter('commission_publisher') * $transaction->getPrice() / 100, 2);
    }
}
```

and there is a problem i want to use the function in my twig. My twig looks like

```
<span class="rab_mobile">{{ 'table.head.net_price'|trans }}:</span>
{% if t.isNormalPrice() %}
    {{ t.price|localizedcurrency(currency) }}
{% else %}
    <em>{{ t.alternativePayment|slice(0,15) }}</em>
{% endif %}
```

I want to add commission in twig.
Can anyone suggest me how I can do this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a php function in Twig, you might need to create a new extension.

```
class calculateThingsForPaymentsExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function calculateCommission(Transaction $transaction)
    {
        if ($transaction->getPaymentType() == Order::PAYMENT_TYPE_ALTERNATIVE)
        {
            //your logic
        }
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return (array(new \Twig_Function('calculateCommission',
                                         array($this, 'calculateCommission'))));
    }
}
```

And then, in Twig

```
{% set commission = calculateCommission(transaction) %}
```

I used this in Symfony 4 and my class was automatically registered as service and could be used as is.

Assuming you're using Twig with Symfony, you can read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) for more informations.